# Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I am getting this error while trying to write txt file to local path in windows.

Error:
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z

- Spark , hadoop versions : spark-3.0.3-bin-hadoop2.7.
- winutils is placed in C:\winutils\bin
- hadoop.dll is placed in C:\winutils\bin and c:\System32
- Environment Variables set
  HADOOP_HOME  C:\winutils
  Path  %HADOOP_HOME%\bin
- Tried restarting

Comment: What java version? Can you show output of `hadoop checknative -a`?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. 
Java 11.      Output of   hadoop checknative -a       "  'hadoop' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.  "     However i have my path variable defined for hadoop as i mentioned earlier.

Comment: The variable doesn't matter if there is no `hadoop` cmd, exe, or bat file inside the winutils\bin folder... Realistically, I suggest you use WSL2 Linux environment where hadoop (and Spark) commands will run much easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found below cause and solution:

**Root Cause:**
Gradle dependency was with higher version of spark. I have spark 3.0.3 installed but here it was 3.2.0
implementation 'org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.13:3.2.0'

**Fix:**
Replaced with
implementation 'org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.12:3.0.3'